# Not Sure About How to Construct Binary Trees

Tags: java, list, tree, binary-tree

I've just started learning about non-linear data structures in Java. I think I understand the basic concepts for trees and some of the ways in which they can be used.

However, I'm confused about how to actually construct a bigger binary tree from smaller sub-trees. The textbook I'm using suggests using a list to hold the subtrees but it is extremely vague about describing exactly how you link the subtrees together using this strategy.

If you have a tree class and a node class where each subtree has a root node and each node has a reference to its two child nodes as shown below, what is a good (and not overly complicated) way to create a larger binary tree?

A simple example of using an unordered list (or similar) to do this would really help me to understand this better.

```
public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTreeADT<T>, Iterable<T>
{
    protected BinaryTreeNode<T> root; 
    protected int modCount;

    /**
     * Creates an empty binary tree.
     */
    public LinkedBinaryTree() 
    {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a binary tree with the specified element as its root.
     *
     * @param element the element that will become the root of the binary tree
     */
    public LinkedBinaryTree(T element) 
    {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a binary tree with the specified element as its root and the 
     * given trees as its left child and right child
     *
     * @param element the element that will become the root of the binary tree
     * @param left the left subtree of this tree
     * @param right the right subtree of this tree
     */
    public LinkedBinaryTree(T element, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left, 
                            LinkedBinaryTree<T> right) 
    {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
        root.setLeft(left.root);
        root.setRight(right.root);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the element at the root
     *
     * @return a reference to the specified target
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty
     */
    public T getRootElement() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        return root.getElement();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the node at the root
     *
     * @return a reference to the specified node
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty
     */
    protected BinaryTreeNode<T> getRootNode() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the left subtree of the root of this tree.
     *
     * @return a link to the left subtree fo the tree
     */
    public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getLeft()
    {
        return root.getLeft();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the right subtree of the root of this tree.
     *
     * @return a link to the right subtree of the tree
     */
    public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getRight()
    {
        return root.getRight();
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this binary tree is empty and false otherwise.
     *
     * @return true if this binary tree is empty, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        return (root == null);
    }
```

The Node Class:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T>
{
    protected T element;
    protected BinaryTreeNode<T> left, right;

    /**
     * Creates a new tree node with the specified data.
     *
     * @param obj the element that will become a part of the new tree node
    */
    public BinaryTreeNode(T obj) 
    {
        element = obj;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new tree node with the specified data.
     *
     * @param obj the element that will become a part of the new tree node
     * @param left the tree that will be the left subtree of this node
     * @param right the tree that will be the right subtree of this node
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode(T obj, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left, LinkedBinaryTree<T> right) 
    {
        element = obj;
        if (left == null)
            this.left = null;
        else
            this.left = left.getRootNode();

         if (right == null)
            this.right = null;
        else
            this.right = right.getRootNode();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of non-null children of this node.
     *
     * @return the integer number of non-null children of this node 
     */
    public int numChildren() 
    {
        int children = 0;

        if (left != null)
            children = 1 + left.numChildren();

        if (right != null)
            children = children + 1 + right.numChildren();

        return children;
    }

    /**
     * Return the element at this node.
     *
     * @return the element stored at this node
     */
    public T getElement() 
    {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Return the right child of this node.
     *
     * @return the right child of this node
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRight() 
    {
        return right;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the right child of this node.
     *
     * @param node the right child of this node
     */
    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) 
    {
        right = node;
    }

    /**
     * Return the left child of this node.
     *
     * @return the left child of the node
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeft() 
    {
        return left;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the left child of this node.
     *
     * @param node the left child of this node
     */
    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) 
    {
        left = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a "flat" indexed list of some kind (ArrayList, for example), I've typically seen binary trees implemented this way: for any node at index `n`, the left child would be at index `2*n` and the right child would be at index `(2*n)+1` (with indexes starting at 1, not 0). Also remember that each node in a tree can technically be considered the root of a subtree. That doesn't directly answer your question, but maybe it helps you a little.